# Is it possible to refer to css styles as objects in JS code?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I want to be able to do this:

```
import styles from 'switchstyle.css';

const Choice = function (props) {
    const cssClasses = [];

    if (props.active) {
        // i think .active would be defined in the css file
        cssClasses.push(style.active);
    }

    return (
        <div
            onClick={props.onClick}
            className={cssClasses}
        >
            {props.label}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I saw something like that in a React book, but I cant get it to work -- I think I am missing some webpack plugin (I am guessing).   THank you

Comment: Why haven't you marked correct answers for any of your past questions? It helps others find the right answer when searching. Make sure to click the empty checkmark next to correct answers.

Comment: @alernerdev What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine assuming you're using Webpack, except `className` can't take an array. A simple solution is to make it a string:

```
className={cssClasses.join(' ')}
```